# Android Resource Identifier for High Resolution Phones and Google TVs

Tags: android, google-tv, android-resources

Which resource identifier can I use for Google TVs to distinguish it from phones like the Galaxy S3, layout-sw720dp doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the tvdpi, but unfortunately the Galaxy S3 was picking up its resources.  I ended up using layout and layout-large for the resources.  The Nexus and Google TVs get their resources from layout-large and the Galaxy S3 gets its resources from layout. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tvdpi`:

> Resources for screens somewhere between mdpi and hdpi; approximately
>   213dpi. This is not considered a "primary" density group. It is mostly
>   intended for televisions and most apps shouldn't need it—providing
>   mdpi and hdpi resources is sufficient for most apps and the system
>   will scale them as appropriate. If you find it necessary to provide
>   tvdpi resources, you should size them at a factor of 1.33*mdpi. For
>   example, a 100px x 100px image for mdpi screens should be 133px x
>   133px for tvdpi.

Comment: Thanks, so if I want to have a different layout for the Galaxy phone than the tv, I would place the tv resources in layout-tvdpi?  And just layout for the phones?

Comment: Note that while `tvdpi` excludes the Galaxy Nexus, you probably shouldn't use this alone to try to identify a Google TV device. The Nexus 7 also uses `tvdpi`. (http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/07/getting-your-app-ready-for-jelly-bean.html)

Answer (score 0):

TV setting  Addressable screen size (in pixels) Density identifier  screen density (in dp)  Display resolution (in dp)  Screen size identifier

- 720p    1280 x 720 px   tvdpi   213 960 x 540   large
- 1080p   1920 x 1080 px  xhdpi   320 960 x 540   large

This is from: https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_android_patterns

More detailed info on display guideline: https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_displayguide